# How to sorting a dataframe by a permutation of a column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with like this

|  | RunID | RackID | PartID | HandID | Ultra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 6 | 61 | 4 | 24 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | 59 | 11 | 33 |
| 2 | 3 | 1 | 37 | 18 | 17 |
| 3 | 4 | 4 | 28 | 112 | 55 |
| 4 | 5 | 3 | 45 | 31 | 246 |
| 5 | 6 | 5 | 73 | 29 | 26 |

Now I would like to reorder the dataframe by a permutation of the column 'RackID'
The expected result is like this:

|  | RunID | RackID | PartID | HandID | Ultra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 5 | 3 | 45 | 31 | 246 |
| 3 | 4 | 4 | 28 | 112 | 55 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | 59 | 11 | 33 |
| 2 | 3 | 1 | 37 | 18 | 17 |
| 0 | 1 | 6 | 61 | 4 | 24 |
| 5 | 6 | 5 | 73 | 29 | 26 |

How to achieve this result in Pandas? Any thought? Thanks.

I used reindex and iloc, seems like the results were not what I want.

Comment: Did any of the answers below work?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can you try something like this:

```
df.set_index('RackID').reindex([3,4,2,1,6,5]).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   RackID  RunID  PartID  HandID  Ultra
0       3      5      45      31    246
1       4      4      28     112     55
2       2      2      59      11     33
3       1      3      37      18     17
4       6      1      61       4     24
5       5      6      73      29     26
```

Answer (score 0):

Using loc, you can use-

```
df.loc[df.index[df["RackID"].values-1]]

192 µs ± 13.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

and can achieve the same using -

```
df.sort_values("RackID"], inplace=True)

60.1 µs ± 838 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

These timings are based on smaller dataset and may vary with larger datasets.